# Can a div fill up the entire viewport with a pixel-based margin, not using the CSS3 calc property?

Tags: css, css-calc

I've found a (hacky) way to have a div take up the full viewport of a browser, minus a pixel-based margin, by utilizing the CSS3 `calc` property like so (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f0soatp/)):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  height: calc(100% - 26px);
  margin: 13px 0 0 13px;
  width: calc(100% - 26px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with only CSS 2.1 properties? I know calc has been supported in most browsers for quite some time but it [also looks like the most popular polyfills have their limitations](https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill#user-content-specificity). I have been beating my head against the wall trying to find a more elegant solution - for instance, one where I don't have to lock down the oversized viewport with `overflow:hidden`. It seems close to impossible to do without the use of `calc` or `vh` / `vw` units.

Comment: You could use `absolute` or `fixed` positioning with `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` set to the required margin size, or create a wrapper element with padding and use `100%` sizing for both

Comment: [calc()](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-notation)'s not hacky. It's HTML standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the width you don't need to do anything since it will by default take all the space. And for height you can consider padding on the body and use `height:100%`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  padding: 13px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 13px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Or padding on all the sides without margin:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Or a fixed element and you don't have to bother setting width/height on body/html

```css
body > div {
  position:fixed;
  top:13px;
  left:13px;
  bottom:13px;
  right:13px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

You can also consider the use of transparent border:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(red, yellow) padding-box;
  height: 100%;
  border:13px solid transparent;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, or, if you need to specify this explicitly (for instance, if you need to reset it when the width has been changed previously) set the value to `width: auto`.

Comment: Thanks! The third example makes the most sense to me, so I'm going to go with that.

Comment: Moreover, only the third example doesn't use the box-sizing property, which like calc, is not a CSS 2.1 property

Answer (score 0):

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        div {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        div::before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 13px;
            left: 13px;
            bottom: 13px;
            right: 13px;
            content: '';
            background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Gradient div</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can simply try the following CSS:

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    div {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    div::before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        left: 13px;
        bottom: 13px;
        right: 13px;
        content: '';
        background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    }
```

Comment: I like this solution as well! Easy to forget how powerful the  `::before` pseudoclass is.